# Facebook Graph API is not returning the property user_birthday

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web

I'm using Facebook Graph API to return user information for my app. So far I only needed to get the email as an extended property and I never had any problem with it. However, now I have to get the user birthday, but it is not working as expected. I am getting a null value.

Here is part of the class I use to return the information

```
using DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2;

namespace Contoso.Web.Mvc.Controls.Authentication.IdentityProviders
{
    public class FacebookIdentityProvider : IdentityProvider
    {      

        public override ActionResult Authenticate(Func<LoginParameters, ActionResult> CallbackFunction)
        {
            var authorization = fbClient.ProcessUserAuthorization();
            var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);

            if (authorization == null && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Parameters.AccessToken))
            {
                //Kick off authorization request
                fbClient.RequestUserAuthorization(scope: new string[] { "email", "user_birthday"});
            }
            else
            {
                if(authorization != null)
                    Parameters.AccessToken = authorization.AccessToken;

                var request = WebRequest.Create("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(Parameters.AccessToken));

                using (var response = request.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        var graph = FacebookGraph.Deserialize(responseStream);
                        var user = GetUser(graph);
                        var requiresExtraInformation = false;
                        DoFormAuthenticationAndCreateUserIfNeeded(user, out requiresExtraInformation);

                        if (requiresExtraInformation)
                        {
                            return RedirectToExtraInformationPage(user);
                        }
                        return CallbackFunction(Parameters);                              
                    }
                }
            }

            return new RedirectResult(urlHelper.Action("Index"));
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class FacebookGraph
    {
        private static DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(FacebookGraph));

        [DataMember(Name = "id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "first_name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "last_name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "gender")]
        public string Gender { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "user_birthday")]
        public string UserBirthday { get; set; }

        public static FacebookGraph Deserialize(string json)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("jsonStream");
            }

            return Deserialize(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)));
        }

        public static FacebookGraph Deserialize(Stream jsonStream)
        {
            if (jsonStream == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("jsonStream");
            }
            return (FacebookGraph)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(jsonStream);
        }
    }
}
```

When I deserialize the response I get from facebook I get all the information I need except for the user birthday (it appears as null). I checked and my facebook profile does have the user birthday.

Comment: Do you have that information shared for the user you are testing with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found the problem and it was a little bit silly, but I'm leaving it here in case someone else stumbles upon this.

The problem was that even though I was requesting the correct scope "user_birthday", the property in the graph object is just called "birthday", so instead of having this

```
[DataMember(Name = "user_birthday")]
public string UserBirthday { get; set; }
```

I should have this

```
[DataMember(Name = "birthday")]
public string UserBirthday { get; set; }
```

And that's it. It's working now!